# Requisição Ajax Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro ao enviar ao enviar a dados json via ajax usando o codeigniter: Disallowed Key Characters.
Quando envio apenas um objeto funciona sem problemas, mas quando envio mais de um objeto me retorna o erro.

```
jQuery.post( "http://localhost/endereco", 
                    {informacao1:"dado1", informacao2:"dado2"},
                    function(data){     

                            alert(data);

                    }   
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que vc pode fazer é criar um arquivo `MY_Input.php` dentro de application/core

```
<?php

class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

    /**
     * Clean Keys
     *
     * This is a helper function. To prevent malicious users
     * from trying to exploit keys we make sure that keys are
     * only named with alpha-numeric text and a few other items.
     * 
     * Extended to allow: 
     *      - '.' (dot), 
     *      - '[' (open bracket),
     *      - ']' (close bracket)
     * 
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _clean_input_keys($str)
    {
        if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/\.\[\]-]+$/i", $str) )
        {
            exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
        }

        // Clean UTF-8 if supported
        if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
        {
            $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
        }

        return $str;
    }

}
```

Comment: Mas este método já não existe dentro do arquivo system/core/input.php?

Comment: Mesmo assim criei e não funcionou.

Comment: Sim, mas tem uma pequena alteração. Eu estava com esse mesmo problema e o que me resolveu foi isso. Tenta dar uma olhada nesse link. https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/140333/#854563

Comment: O link me ajudou. Nem precisei criar o arquivo. Apenas alterei o método _clean_input_keys do arquivo system/core/input.php da forma que você escreveu. Obrigado.

Comment: Mas não é aconselhado alterar nada de `system` e sim criar o arquivo no seu diretório `application/[core|libraries]` e com isso, se um dia, sair uma versão nova, só irá precisar alterar a pasta system sem maiores problemas.